# Confused about UMVE and Linear Combination of Two Unbiased Estimators, Taking Unif (0, $\theta$) as an Example

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, unbiased-estimator, statsmodels, umvue

A dumb question here ...

I am confused about UMVE and Linear Combination of Two Unbiased Estimator (that can potentially create a more efficient/lower-variance estimator).

Taking $\mathcal{Unif}(0, \theta)$ as an example and our target parameter is $\theta$. We know there are [two unbiased estimators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60497/unbiased-estimator-for-a-uniform-variable-support)  and the order statistic one is UMVE (or UMVUE).

However, [this](https://vamshij.com/blog/statistical-inference/minimum-variance-unbiased-estimator/) somehow tells us we can find a optimal linear combination of two \theta unbiased estimators and deliver a even better one (in terms of lower variance).

Which part of my understanding is wrong?

Would like to better understand the relationship between UMVE and linear combination between two unbiased estimators.

Comment: You should check for a,b being either 0,1 or 1,0

Comment: I mean, you are looking for optimal estimator. It might be on the left or the right side of a/b range 0...1